# how to get shortname of month in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

i have successfully find the full name of month but i want short name of month. Can anyone help me. I am using Moment.js i have successfully find the month but i want in short form
here is my code :

```
var date = '<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>';
var Month = moment(date, 'YYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MMMM')
console.log(Month);
```

it returns me `06/February`, But i want `06/Feb`

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You are not using correct format string, use `MMM` instead of `MMMM` see [Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

```js
console.log(moment().format('DD/MMM'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

As an addendum to **Satpal's** answer, a simpler (kind of faster/safer approach) would be to go with the **Localized formats** because preferred formatting differs based on locale.

```
moment().format('ll') - Sep 4, 1986
```

Where as

```
moment().format('LL') - September 4, 1986
```

Optionally to include time:

```
moment().format('lll') - Sep 4, 1986 8:30 PM
```

Where as

```
moment().format('LLL') - September 4, 1986 8:30 PM
```

Answer (score 6):

use below month formats to get required output :

[image]

```js
console.log(`Month Number : moment().format('M') ==> `,moment().format('M'))

console.log(`Month Number : moment().format('Mo') ==> `,moment().format('Mo'))

console.log(`Month Number : moment().format('MM') ==> `,moment().format('MM'))

console.log(`3 Letter Month Name : moment().format('MMM') ==> `,moment().format('MMM'))

console.log(`Full Month Name : moment().format('MMMM') ==> `,moment().format('MMMM'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `moment(date, 'YYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MMM')` .